# MariaDB INSERT - How can I increment a counter on duplicates?

Tags: mariadb, counter, sql-insert, increment, on-duplicate-key

I am writing event-log data to a MariaDB database.  The primary key includes the time to one-second granularity.  I sometimes get bursts of identical input data.  This violates the key and is currently ignored.

I'd like to add a counter field to the table so that, if identical data arrive in the same second, the counter shows how many identical items were received.

I would like an equivalent to the following made-up syntax

```
INSERT INTO T (a, b, c, counter) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE T.counter = 1+T.counter;
```

I can do this with a stored procedure but is it possible without?

I've spent over an hour searching for answers but I believe that my keywords are too close to various common problems involving auto-increment SERIAL fields.

Comment: Do you want to use plain SQL? If yes, why don't substitute the place holders by values ?

Comment: If counter can be any incremantal number (1...n) you must add more complex logic to retrieve the last counter and increment it by 1

Comment: @Pippo why?  that's what `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE T.counter = T.counter + ...` does

Comment: @ysth ok, i was misunderstanding the situation, it could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "made-up" syntax works exactly as is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```sql
INSERT INTO T (a, b, c, counter)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE counter = counter + VALUES(counter);
```

Comment: `VALUES(counter)` is always going to be just 1